# Is possible to use retina options/large text for iMac 2011 with 2k/4k Monitor?

Tags: display, macos, imac

I have a [Samsung U32H75](http://www.samsung.com/pe/monitors/u32h75/) with iMac 21" 2011. I wish to make the fonts large for the UI. I try enabling retina with

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist DisplayResolutionEnabled -bool true
```

But nothing show after reboot.

Is this possible.

Comment: Did you update OSX to the current version?

Comment: I have Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: I'm wondering why Retina is disabled in the first place then. Even on my 2009 iMac it goes in Retina mode automatically with a 4k monitor connected.

Comment: Does it work when you "brew cask install switchresx" and change it to HiDPI there?

Comment: Did you push the option key when clicking "custom resolution"?

Comment: With option key not show. All are "low resolution" except the 4k and Full HD

Comment: With switchresx only show with HDPI upto 1280x800

Comment: Again, just that I understand the problem right : With switchres, you CAN switch to 3860 but you CANNOT switch to 1920 with HiDpi, correct? I'm learning something here actually.

Comment: No, 1920 is not marked with HiDpi. Only up to 1280x800.

Comment: Sorry, 1280 (Meaing 2560 native) of course. Maybe it is because of the cable/adapter you are using and it limits your DisplayPort specification. How do you connect the monitor to your iMac?